# SSL Certificate on Android

Tags: android, ssl

I have a website that uses HTTPS with a SSL certificate, when I open the website on a android device and go through the steps of installing the certificate, I get this error NET::ERR_CERT_VALIDITY_TOO_LONG. My certificate expires 5 years after the website has been installed. I believe android has 27-39 month limit. How do I get passed this without having to change my certificate expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get passed this without having to change my certificate?

You simply don't. The validation of a certificate is done at the client and the server cannot issue any magic to make the client check the certificate differently. This means that you need to change your certificate.

Comment: Sorry I meant without having to change the expiration date.  I want to keep the 5 years expiration date so my users don't have to change certificate so often

Comment: @user173092: Like I said, this is not possible. The decision what is considered an acceptable range for expiration is fully up to the client side and the server cannot make the client accept a longer expiration. *"I want to keep the 5 years expiration date so my users don't have to change certificate so often"*  - As long as you don't pin to a specific certificate "users" (i.e. Android clients) don't have to change the certificate at all since they simply will accept a renewed certificate if it is issued by a CA they trust.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one SSL certificate for a domain. So, without changing your current certificate that has a 5 year expiration, obtain a new one ([LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) gives you free certificates) with the requisite expiration and install that.

This is assuming you control the HTTPS website as well. If not, you are out of luck and have to wait for the website provider to update the cert.